# Php arrays -- one title a few record

Tags: php

i have a problem with php in arrays.

i have a db table like that , it shows applications to job.
[image]

What i want is to order job titles with their files for example

title must be shown :
 
WEB Tasarım Uzmanı 
noktamedya.com/CVs/zsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf.docx
noktamedya.com/CVs/zsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf.docx

İçerik Yöneticisi
noktamedya.com/CVs/abc.docx
noktamedya.com/CVs/abc.docx

i have a class which takes to important record from db

```
 public function getAllRec()
         {
             $query = "SELECT * FROM applyRecords ";
             $resultDb = $this->db->query ($query);
             $jobs = array ();

        while ( $row = $resultDb->fetchObject () ) {
            $job = new Job ();
            $job->title = $row->jobTitle;
                        $job->url = $row->file;

            $jobs [] = $job;
        }
        return $jobs;
         }
```

i have here to file and jobTitle. 
in admin inc. i call this function like that

```
$jobs3 = $jobHome->getAllRec();
```

and try to order with their jobTitle but have error and dont understand

```
foreach($jobs3 as $job)
{
    $groupJobs = [$job->title][$job->url] = $job;
}
```

what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to do:
Group job applications by title of job applying to

```
$groupJobs = array();
foreach($job3 as $job){
   if(!isset($groupJobs[$job->title])){
       $groupJobs[$job->title] = array();
   }
   $groupJobs[$job->title][] = $job; // add job to group
}
```

Comment: and then i did this foreach($groupJobs as $key => $value){
    
    echo $key . "<br />";
    echo $value;
   
}

Comment: Actually $job is object, so to retrieve url you need 2 nested foreach loops: foreach($groupJopb as $title => $jobs){ foreach($jobs as $job){ echo $title . ' - ' . $job->url; }  }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ordering in PHP, order in SQL, and then continue.

Instead of

```
"SELECT * FROM applyRecords "
```

try

```
"SELECT * FROM applyRecords ORDER BY jobtitle "
```

Comment: but gives error here foreach($jobs3 as $job)
{
    $groupJobs = [$job->title][$job->url] = $job;
}

Comment: Is there a title column in db? It should be jobTitle, same for url, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$groupJobs = [$job->title][$job->url] = $job;
```

This is not valid php syntax. I can't even see what are you trying to do here but I make a wild guess:

```
$groupJobs[] = array(
    "title" => $job->title,
    "urls" => array($job->url1, $job->url2)
);
```

About the ordering: You should add a parameter for this and let sql do to ordering:

```
public function getAllRec($order)
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM applyRecords ";
    if ($order) $query .= " ORDER BY " . $order;
    $resultDb = $this->db->query ($query);
    ...
```

Comment: but also i try to print jobTitle  one JobTitle  a few url

Comment: I am not sure how you want to display the urls and where you get them from. But you can store the in an array. See above.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$groupJobs[$job->title] = array(
    $job->url => $job
);
```

The groupJobs Array Must be defined as Array before foreach.
And remember, $job is an object.

Answer (score 0):

Just sort the records at the time of database fetch

```
"SELECT * FROM applyRecords ORDER BY jobTitle"
```

Answer (score 0):

My final answer is below

```
$groupJobs = array();

foreach($jobs3 as $job)
{
    $groupJobs[$job->title][] = $job;

}

foreach($groupJobs as $key => $value){

     $key . "<br />";
    foreach($value as $node){
         $node->url;
         $node->name;
    }

}
```

Thank you all.